# Passing data to on()

Tags: jquery

```
var i = 1;

$('select').on("change", i, function () {
    alert(i);
});
```

This is not doing anything and I am unsure why...

```
var i = 1;

$('select').change(function (i) {
    alert(i);
});
```

This is returning [object Object]

Anyway I would like to be able to pass an int to the change method and cannot see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Pass an `int` from where? In either case, the change handler is bound to `select` elements on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter in the function in the event is not one you pass, it's the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/event-object/), and it's passed by jQuery when the event is ran.

You can pass a value to [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), and its value will appear in [`event.data`](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/).

Example:

```
var i = 1;

$('select').on("change", i, function (e) {
    alert(e.data);  // e.data will be the variable passed to .on
});
```

Or since you are declaring `i` outside the function, you can just use it inside.

```
var i = 1;

$('select').on("change", function (e) {
    alert(i);
});
```

Comment: first code example is the right answere. make sure that `i` is not a string, otherwise you have to call `$('select').on("change", null, i, function (e) { ...`

Comment: I always thought you are supposed to pass an object as `data` argument, but it works indeed!

Comment: @FelixKling: It doesn't have to be an object.  I thought so too, but then I tried it :-)

Comment: @lrsjng: Good call, otherwise it'd be interpreted as the `selector` argument.

Answer (score 2):

The below code should work since `i` is a global variable

```
var i = 1;

$('select').on("change", function() {
    alert(i);
});
```

or if you want to pass `i` as data to the event then this will also work:

```
var i = 1;
$('select').on("change", {i: i}, function(e) {
    alert(e.data.i);
});
```

Comment: well for whatever reason this is not triggering the alert.

Comment: show some html and we can work it out. Maybe your selector is incorrect

Comment: Don't just copy and paste code from other answers, you will copy the mistakes as well :P But at least I noticed now that I made an error, so thanks.

Comment: Don't you mean `e.data.value`?

Answer (score 1):

> This is returning [object Object]
>
> ```
> $('select').change(function (i) {
>     alert(i);
> });
> ```

This is not passing the variable `i` to your event handler, this is **defining** your handler with the first parameter having the **name** `i`. When the event is triggered, the handler is called and passed the current **event object** as first argument, i.e. `i` refers to that [event object *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/category/event-object/).

You can only pass arguments to functions you when you **call** them, not when you **define** them.

---

> This is not doing anything and I am unsure why...
>
> ```
> $('select').on("change", i, function () {
>    alert(i);
> });
> ```

The second argument you pass to `.on` is supposed to be a string containing a selector, which allows event delegation, or <del>an object containing</del> data you want to make available inside the event handler. This data is not directly passed to the event handler though, it's accesible via the event object's `.data` property (see below).

---

With that said, you have two possibilites:

1. Use your handler as a closure, like [Omar shows in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12863975/218196). But be aware that whenever `i` changes and the event handler is executed, it will have the current value of `i`.
2. If you want to "pass" a snapshot of `i`, i.e. the value that it has at the time you define the event handler, you can, as already said, pass a data object to `.on` which you can access via the event object in your handler:

   ```
   $('select').on("change", {value: i}, function(event) {
       alert(event.data.value);
   });
   ```

   See [`event.data` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/) for more information.

---

I highly recommend to read the [`.on` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/on/) documentation. It contains a lot of information about how it and event handling in jQuery works. You also seem to not fully understand how functions work, in which case you should have a look at the MDN JavaScript Guide [section about functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Functions).

Answer (score 0):

This could help:

1) when you do

```
$('select').on('change',i,function(ev){...});
```

then the value i, will be assigned to the ev.data.
so in your handler, you can do :

```
$('select').on('change',i,function(ev){
     alert(ev.data)
});
```

2) To better understand why the second one doesnt work as you expected because in JS, you may want to read about how scoping works in JS.

But the summary is , variable i that you are accessing in your alert is the local variable in the event handler scope.

```
function(i){ alert(i) },// here i is the event object .
```

simply change the variable name to x and it should work.

```
var i = 1;

$('select').change(function (x) {
    alert(i);
});
```